# Running dotnet build on a .net rc2 projects fails with 'path2' error

Tags: c#, .net

With no appparent reason when I run `dotnet build` on my project I get the following error.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
```

That is the full error, nothing else is output.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone receiving this what I ended up doing was deleting the project and restoring it from version control, after a fresh `dotnet restore` build started working again.